# There are 12 keys. Bag A contains 5 keys and bag B contains 7 keys. Only one key can open the door: what's the probability it lies in bag A?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

I think this is supposed to be quite a simple question however it's been a long long time since I touched probability or maths in general so I could be completely wide of the mark here.

Here's my thinking...

Total number of ways 12 keys could be distributed into two groups of 5 and 7 is:
$$\dfrac{12!}{5!7!}$$

We are interested in the event that the key lies in bag A. Supposing it is in bag A, the number of choices for the remaining spots is:
$$\dfrac{11!}{4!7!}$$

So the answer is surely the bottom fraction divided by the above fraction which is about $0.42$ - is my reasoning correct? I sense that I have made an error.

Comment: It is simpler than that.  Your answer is correct, you are just working a lot harder than you need to.

Comment: It's literally just 5/12 isn't it. Thing is, I don't understand why it's that simple.

Comment: There are 12 places you key could be.  5 of those places are in bag A.

Comment: Understand it now. Very simple.

Answer (score 3):

An octave on a piano has seven white keys, and five black keys.

If I'm thinking of one of the keys, what is the probability that it is black?

Comment: Hah, my good sir I have made a catastrophic oversight it seems. How silly of me.

Comment: We've all been there.